# Method set of a receiver type

Tags: go

[Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) says:

> The method set of a type determines the interfaces that the type implements and the methods **that can be called** using a receiver of that type.

---

So, to verify the point, below is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// I interf
type I interface {
    hello()
    goodbye()
}

// T type
type T struct {
    name string
}

func (t T) hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello", t.name)
}

func (t *T) goodbye() {
    fmt.Println("Goodbye", t.name)
}

func main() {
    var t1 T = T{"James"}
    t1.hello()
    t1.goodbye()
}
```

---

`t1.goodbye()` works despite `goodbye()` method is **not part of method set** of type `T`. Because, `t1.goodbye()` works internally as `(&t1).goodbye()` that satisfies below rule:

> If you have a `T` and it isn't addressable, you can only call methods that have a receiver type of `T`, not `*T`.

---

But, specs says, method calling follows below rule:

> The method set of a type determines the interfaces that the type implements and the methods **that can be called** using a receiver of that type.

Does invocation of `t1.goodbye()` as `(&t1).goodbye()` break method calling rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) in the spec...

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()

- t1 is addressable.
- &t1's method set contains goodbye().
- t1.goodbye() is shorthand for (&t1).goodbye().